# How to unbox an array of string?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have an array of string boxed to an object:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
object obj = files;
```

How can I unboxed the `files` into array of string again?

Comment: Beware your wording: strings do not "box." What you have done is implicitly convert the string array to object, but no boxing is involved, nor is any unboxing. To clarify, boxing and unboxing are terms used when value types are converted to and from reference types. System.String is not a value type.

Comment: Continued: An array of strings is also not a value type, nor is an array of *anything* a value type. The terms you'd want to use are *cast* and *convert*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The as operator is like a cast except that it yields null on conversion failure instead of raising an exception. [As operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
string[] someVarArray = obj as string[] 
if(someVarArray!=null)
{
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a **cast**, not boxing and unboxing.

```
string[] files2 = (string[])obj;
```

But be aware, do this if you are sure that your object contains an array of strings (string[]), or otherwise you get an **InvalidCastException**.
If you are not sure, you have two ways to test the object:

```
string[] files2;
if( o is string[] )
{
    files2 = (string[])o;
    // do whatever with files2
}
```

or

```
string[] files2 = o as string[];
if( files2 != null )
{
    // do whatever with files2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use the as operator..

```
if ( obj is string[])
    string[] files = obj as string[];
```

you could just "cast" it back....

```
if ( obj is string[])
    string[] files = (string[])obj;
```